# Get the DataRow corresponding to the selected row in Excel ListObject

Tags: excel, datatable, vsto, listobject

I develop a vsto addin for Excel. I feed ListObject with DataTable by databinding. When user select a row the Excel table (ListObject) I want to get the DataRow in DataTable source which corresponds to this selected row.

Any way?

wr

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.NET?

Comment: I use C# language

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I haven't no code show as I haven't find any way to link DataTable source and Range in Excel ListOject

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check up the details of DataSets and how the update can go forward to the actual table at
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(VS.80).aspx.

Some of the steps in working with DataSets include:

In a typical multiple-tier implementation, the steps for creating and refreshing a DataSet, and in turn, updating the original data are to:

1. Build and fill each DataTable in a DataSet with data from a data source using a [DataAdapter](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter(VS.80).aspx).
2. Change the data in individual DataTable objects by adding, updating, or deleting [DataRow](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(VS.80).aspx) objects.
3. Invoke the [GetChanges](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getchanges(VS.80).aspx) method to create a second DataSet that features only the changes to the data.
4. Call the [Update](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(VS.80).aspx) method of the DataAdapter, passing the second DataSet as an argument.
5. Invoke the [Merge](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.merge(VS.80).aspx) method to merge the changes from the second DataSet into the first.
6. Invoke the [AcceptChanges](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges(VS.80).aspx) on the DataSet. Alternatively, invoke [RejectChanges](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.rejectchanges(VS.80).aspx) to cancel the changes.

Its important to note that ListObject allows you to bind to a DataSet, the responsibility of actual update happening accross on the physical database is that of the developer.

As far as collecting the changes from ListObject, you can use the ListObject.Change event and it passes the targetRange which has changed as one of the values. TargetRange.Value2 has the value of all the cells that have changed. (It could be an object, object[], or object[,]).

Comment: Thanks I will try this method.

Comment: Any luck with this?